# OPENQUERY mismatching data in records after Upgrade ---update --Only on CLOB columns

Tags: sql-server, oracle

We are having an issue with openquery() after our source database upgraded to ORACLE 19c.  We had no issues before.   However now when we query against the database using openquery the primary keys seem to be associated with the incorrect records.  IF we include a where clause in the openquery portion defining a particular ID (primary key) then we get the correct result.

I have queried the ORACLE db directly and the IDs/record associations are correct.  It is only when using openquery() and only after the 19c upgrade that this issue occurred.  Admin is stating we are using the correct ODBC driver.

Anyone else ever seen an issue like this?

Thanks!

------------------------------UPDATE 1 !!!!!!!!

Additional Info Added:
I looked a bit further and it looks like only CLOB column is being attached to the wrong record using openquery. The rest of the columns are correct.
Name       Null?    Type

---

REC_ID  NOT NULL VARCHAR2(8)
SEQ_NBR    NOT NULL NUMBER
BEGIN_DATE          CHAR(8)
END_DATE            CHAR(8)
RC_ID      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(4)
ID_DESC            CLOB

------------------------------UPDATE 2 !!!!!!!!
Our work around
We rolled back our ODBC driver and this fixed our issues.  We were also able to band aid a few fixes before the driver downgrade by casting the CLOB as a varchar in the OPENQUERY statement.

Comment: Are you using a supported Oracle OleDb provider for your linked server?

Comment: We are.  After digging further it looks like the record is correct for the key value but the CLOB column is not matching.  I found someone having the same issue on another support board.  It was his drivers.  He rolled them back and the CLOB column came back correctly.   I got with a counterpart at another institution who use the same database and had them openquery the table and they seem to be fine but they are using the old drivers.  One response on the other site requested casting the CLOB to a varchar.  I tried this and it worked.  It pulled back the correct CLOB column data.

Comment: Damn, exactly same problem here.